# Convert excel file into text file in python

Tags: python, numpy

After lot of googling also i am posting my question here as I didn't find any perfect solution
Question :
I have excel file and i want to convert it into text file with below conditions
Tab should be replaced with single space
Excel file contains int and float value (Need to be as it is in excel)
What I have tried is

```
 df = pd.read_excel(filename.xlsx, header=None)
    np.savetxt("filenaem.txt", df, fmt='%d %d %d %d %d', delimiter=" ") #5 col
```

Comment: Did you try [`DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) ?

Comment: no as i need specifically .txt file

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_excel("filenaem.xlsx", header=None, usecols = "A:E")
np.savetxt("filenaem.txt", df, fmt='%d %d %d %f %d', delimiter=" ")
```

But 4 th column has int and float.... as I defined it as %f it is converting int to float is there any way to handle it